# Fill a textbox with new data from a stored procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net, stored-procedures

Just trying to fill testbox1 with stored procedure data. currently my code says:

```
<td>
   <a href="/test/test/test/testform.aspx?id=<%row.requestnumber%>"><%=row.requestnumber%></a>
</td>
```

What happens is the id displayed in the url of newly generated `testform.aspx` has the correct value for example `id=363`. It is correctly taking and displaying my stored procedure data.

Where I want to go from here is to have that value display in a textbox on the newly generated page.

Let's say `textbox1`.

Do I put this in the url? The c# file? The html file?

Any suggestions much appreciated and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that `testform.aspx` will have a `TextBox` on it and you want the value to be displayed in that `TextBox` when the user follows this link?  Since you're passing the value as a query string parameter, you can set it in the `Page_Load` event of `testform.aspx`.  Something like this:

```
this.TextBox1.Text = Request.QueryString["id"];
```

(This assumes the `TextBox` is named `TextBox1`.  Which it really shouldn't be, of course.  Just use whatever name you're using.)  If ever an `id` value isn't supplied on the query string, this should silently proceed to just set an empty (or `null` but it makes no difference client-side) value in `TextBox1`.

Comment: i mean it does not work, does not fill the value of the textbox.

Comment: @user3541847: Can you provide a little more information than that?  What is the URL being invoked by the link?  Are there values in the query string?  Are those values available in `Request.QueryString`?  What is the string value being set?  You'll need to do at least *some* debugging.  "It doesn't work" isn't a valid description of the problem.